# Перегрузка операций и работа с множествами

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть задание: "Создать класс Plural, в нем перегрузить такие операции: == множества тождественны, != множества не тождественны, >= надмножество, <= подмножество, ^ вхождение елемента в множество", сам справился с проверкой на тождественные множества(==, !=), но с остальным никак не могу.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Plural
{
  private:
    int elements;
    int* array;
  public:
    Plural(int elements)
    {
        this->elements = elements;
        array = new int[elements];
        cout << "Enter your plural: " << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
        {
            cin >> array[i];
        }
    }

    int* getArrray()
    {
        return this->array;
    }

    bool isPermutation(Plural p1, Plural p2)
    {
        sort(p1.array, p1.array + elements);
        sort(p2.array, p2.array + elements);

        for (int i = 0; i < elements; ++i)
        {
            if (p1.array[i] != p2.array[i])
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    friend void operator==(const Plural& p1, const Plural& p2)
    {
        int count = 0;
        string a = "";

        // bool a = false;
        if (p1.elements == p2.elements)
        {
            // cout << 1;
            sort(p1.array, p1.array + p1.elements);
            sort(p2.array, p2.array + p2.elements);

            for (int i = 0; i < p1.elements; i++)
            {
                if (p1.array[i] == p2.array[i])
                    count++;
            }

            if (count == p1.elements)
            {
                cout << "Plurals are equals" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    friend void operator^ (const Plural& p1 , const int& element)
    {
        bool a = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < p1.elements; i++)
        {
            // cout << this->array[i];
            if (p1.array[i] == element)
            {
                a = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (a) cout << "Plural is contain element" + element << endl;
    }

    friend void operator!=(const Plural& p1, const Plural& p2)
    {
        int count = 0;

        if (p1.elements != p2.elements)
        {
            cout << "Plurals aren`t equals" << endl;
        }
        else if (p1.elements == p2.elements)
        {
            // cout << 1;
            sort(p1.array, p1.array + p1.elements);
            sort(p2.array, p2.array + p2.elements);

            for (int i = 0; i < p1.elements; i++)
            {
                if (p1.array[i] != p2.array[i])
                    count++;
            }

            if (count == p1.elements)
            {
                cout << "Plurals aren`t equals" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
};

void main()
{
    Plural p1 = Plural(3);
    Plural p2 = Plural(3);
    p1 ^ 2;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Засовывать операции и ввода-вывода внутрь алгоритмов - дичайший моветон.

Comment: из-за того, что `operator^` имеет тип void и получаются все "непонимания". Если бы он возвращал bool, то можно было бы сделать цикл и проверить вхождение всех элеметов первого множества в второе (да, будет квадратичная сложность, но для учебного задания сойдет). И это был бы оператор `<=` или `>=` , смотря как проверять. оператор `!=` дублирует опертор `==` тут нужно просто вызвать одно с другого.

Comment: можешь дать пример, как правильно нужно переопределить?

Answer (score 0):

Полный код не буду писать, но покоментирую.

```
bool isPermutation(Plural p1, Plural p2)
```

в этой функции сразу несколько ошибок. Ее сигнатура намекает, что это должна быть отдельно стоящая функция. Внутри функции сравниваются два объекта, а кол-во элементов берется с текущего. Так как кол-во элеметов в текущем объекте вряд ли совпадает с двумя другими - баги будут достаточно интересные. Но самое интересное, если посмотреть на логику, то это просто сравнение на равенство.

```
bool isPermutation(Plural p1, Plural p2) {
  return p1 == p2;
}
```

красивее, не правда?

теперь перепишем сравнение

```
friend bool operator==(const Plural& p1, const Plural& p2)
{
    if (p1.elements != p2.elements) {
      return false;
    }

    sort(p1.array, p1.array + p1.elements);
    sort(p2.array, p2.array + p2.elements);

    for (int i = 0; i < p1.elements; i++)
    {
      if (p1.array[i] != p2.array[i])
      {
         return false;
      }
    return true;
}
```

опять же, сильно проще. сравнили по кол-ву элементов. Если не совпало - даже нет смысла сравнивать. В противном случае сравниваем  поэлементно и как только нашли несовпадающие элементы - "разные" - false.

Но у этой функции есть один существенный минус - функция сравнения изменяет объекты! Это явно не то, что от нее ожидается. Что делать? сортировку можно перенести в конструктор.

оператор ^ вообще прост

```
friend bool operator^ (const Plural& p1 , const int& element)
{
    return std::find(p1.array, p1.array+p1.elements, element) != p1.array+p1.elements;
}
```